# Friedman problem 1.3.1: Show that the cardinality is an outer measure and determine the measureable sets

Tags: measure-theory

> Define $\mu^*(E)$ as the number of points in $E$ if $E$ is finite and $\mu^*(E)=\infty$ if $E$ is infinite. Show that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. Determine the measurable sets.

Evidently, $\mu^*$ is nonegative and monotone, and $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$. Let $E_n$ be a sequence of sets. It remains to show that $\mu^*$ is countably subadditive, i.e.,
$$\tag{1}\mu^*(\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}E_n)\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu^*(E_n)\mbox{.}$$
If $\sum\mu^*(E_n)=\infty$, then there is nothing to prove. Suppose $\sum\mu^*(E_n)<\infty$. Then $\mu^*(E_n)\rightarrow 0$, so that $E_n=\emptyset$ for all values of $n$ form some definite index $N$ onward. Hence (1) reduces to
$$\tag{2}\mu^*(\bigcup^{N-1}_{n=1}E_n)\leq\sum^{N-1}_{n=1}\mu^*(E_n)\mbox{.}$$
But (2) follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle. Therefore $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.

That finite sets are measurable is obvious. What about infinite sets?

Comment: This amounts to showing that finite sets satisfy the Caratheodory Criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the set on which $\mu^*$ is defined. Then $\mu^*$ is additive on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, and thus, every subset of $X$ is measurable.